# consuming classes from folder other than App_Code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, dotnetnuke

I am creating a site wherein I have a folder which contains some .cs files. I want to access those classes in .aspx and .ascx files. I’ve created some properties in it, but when I create the object of the class I don’t find that property via IntelliSense.

How can I use and consume those properties from that .cs file?

Comment: You should add more info, maybe a code sample and where exactly those cs files are located, then we would have a better chance at helping you on the right track =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website will only compile code files that are in the App_Code folder or are codebehind files for referenced controls.  There isn't a way to reference classes defined in code files outside of the App_Code folder.

If you compile those classes and put the resulting dll in your website's bin folder, then you can reference them.  To do that, you'll need to add them to a Web Application project in Visual Studio.  See [Ian Robinson's WAP blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/ianrobinson/archive/2008/10/15/creating-dotnetnuke-modules-using-a-web-application-project-wap.aspx) for most details.

Answer (score 1):

Just have those properties `public` and you'll see them.

If still no luck please post your code and also tell: can you create instance of the class without error? Can you access any other properties or methods?

Comment: i have those folder in the root of the website the folder name is Cross.DNN.Module.Article, and namespace is same as foldername, actually i am using Dotnetnuke, and this is the module of the Dotnetnuke named CrossArticle for managing article. now these folders are shipped with crossarticle itself, now i cant put the cs files inside that in the App_Code. so i want to know how should i access those files, the controls which are shipped with CrossArticle uses these files.. but when i added the new property in this class. i cant see them..

Comment: actually those files are extra source files, which are shipped with CrossArticle, i think CrossArticle are using the classes directly from the DLL. where all these source files are compiled, so how should i modify the code and add the changes in the compiled DLL, so that my controls would access new properties and methods.

Comment: @Abbas you'll have to get the source code of that DLL, add your stuff and compile it again. Otherwise you're pretty much at dead end, sorry.

Comment: i have the source codes of that DLL, but dont know how to compile the changes to the DLL again

Comment: If you have the `.csproj` file as well, open it with Visual Studio, make the changes, right click the project and choose Build. If you only have `.cs` files create new project in Visual Studio, right click --> Properties --> change the assembly name to the name of the DLL --> make changes, right click and build.